# UIGestureRecognizer not recognizing

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I was trying to create a label that should be draggable. But the dragged event is not firing (checked with break point). Below is the code.

```
 - (IBAction)InsertText:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {

    UILabel *lblWatermark = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:currentImage.frame];
    lblWatermark.text = @"Copyright";
    lblWatermark.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [lblWatermark sizeToFit];


    UIPanGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                       initWithTarget:self
                                       action:@selector(labelDragged:)];
    [lblWatermark addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
    [currentImage addSubview:lblWatermark];
}
- (void)labelDragged:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)gesture.view;
    CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:label];

    // move label
    label.center = CGPointMake(label.center.x + translation.x,
                               label.center.y + translation.y);
        [gesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:label];
}
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: have you tried adding the gesture to currentImage instead?  i.e. perhaps sizeToFit is making the UILabel too small for the pan gesture to work properly.  Try adding to the larger view ... if this works try without sizeToFit.

Comment: @CSmith Didnot work either. The label by the way is quite big. Adding the gesture to currentimage is also not firing the event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spotted the error. Actually I had also to make

userInteractionEnabled = YES

Not only for the label But also for the Imageview in which I am adding the label.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your ViewController is the delegate for UIGestureRecognizer with (.h file):

```
@interface View : UIView <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

And then set:

```
 gesture.delegate = self;
```

Comment: the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate is included in .h